# problems with vector<double> f(long int N)

Tags: c++, vector, long-integer

I have the following piece of code that is not working

```
const int N=45;
long int toc;
toc = pow(2, N) - 1;
vector<long double > E(toc);
```

I think the problem is in

```
vector<long double > E(toc);
```

But I can't figure out what is wrong.

The error message is
Debug Error!
Program:..\Curie-Weise.exe

abort() has been called

The code is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>  
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
//Function sum J_ij s_i s_j
double CountSumflip(const vector<vector<double>>& J, const vector<int>& 
spin)
{
double sumflip = 0;
int N = spin.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {
        sumflip += J[i][j] * spin[i] * spin[j];
    }
}
return 2 * sumflip; //izza treugolnika
}

//Function M= sum s_i
int CountMflip(const vector<int>& spin) {

int Mflip = 0;
int N = spin.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    Mflip += spin[i];
}
return Mflip;
}
//Function M= sum b_i s_i
int CountBM(const vector<int>& spin, const vector<int>& Be) {
int BM = 0;
int N = spin.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    BM += Be[i] * spin[i];
}
return BM;
}

//------------------MAIN---------------------------------------------
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int job_number = atoi(argv[1]);

const int N = 40;

std::default_random_engine generator;//Normal generator with 
int seed = 1000000 + 100 * M_PI *  job_number + job_number * job_number;
generator.seed(seed);
std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0.0 /* mean */, 1.0 
/*stddev*/);

std::fstream sfs("perebor_" + std::to_string(job_number) + ".txt", 
std::ios_base::out);
std::fstream sfs2("minimacount_" + std::to_string(job_number) + ".txt", 
std::ios_base::out);
vector<vector<double>> J(N, vector<double>(N));

for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    J[i][i] = 0;
    for (unsigned short int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
    {
        J[i][j] = J[j][i] = distribution(generator);

    }
}

long int minimacount = 0;
for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    for (unsigned short int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        std::cout << J[i][j] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

//----------------Magnetic field generator ------------------------
vector<int> Be(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    Be[i] = 0;// rand() % 2 * 2 - 1;
}




long int num = 0; 
long int toc;
toc = pow(2, N) - 1;
cout <<"2^"<<N<<"= "<< toc << endl;


vector<long double > E(toc);
cout << "ups" << endl;
vector<double> Eflip(N);


for (num = 0; num <toc; num++)
{
    //if (num % 10000 == 0)
    //{
    //  cout << "%" << (num * 1.0 / toc) * 100 << endl;
    //}
    std::bitset<N> bitset = num;
    // 'to_string' вернет строку std::string формата '000...0111'
    //std::cout << "Binary : " << bitset.to_string<char, 
    std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >() << std::endl;
    //string s = bitset.to_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
    std::allocator<char> >();
    vector<int> spin(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (bitset[i])
        {
            spin[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            spin[i] = -1;
        }
        //cout << "spin" << i << "= " << spin[i] << endl;
    }

    E[num] = -CountSumflip(J, spin) - CountBM(spin, Be);

    vector<int> spinflip(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        spinflip[i] = spin[i];
    }

    bool is_local = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        spinflip[i] = -1 * spin[i];
        Eflip[i]= -CountSumflip(J, spinflip) - CountBM(spinflip, Be);
        spinflip[i] = -1 * spin[i];
        if (Eflip[i] < E[num]) {
            is_local = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (is_local) {
        minimacount++;
    }
}

long double d = minimacount*1.0 / pow(2, N);
sfs2  << d << endl;




return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is C++, then please add the c++ tag. And please write what exactly is not working.

Comment: Provide some [MCVE] in your question. In its current state, we cannot guess the code that you don't show in your question, and it matters a lot. Also give the programming language, and the context of your question (what exactly do you want to achieve). So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53801333/edit) your question much more (you probably need to add *several* paragraphs). Explain what is not working. Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Uh, this is an allocation of 262TB of RAM, I think you might not have enough RAM for this

Comment: don't use `toc = pow(2, N) - 1`. Use `(1L << N) - 1` instead which is tens or hundreds of times faster

Comment: My program was working for N less then 35 (int toc). Now I need N more then 35 and hence long int toc must be applied. But then the program is not working anymore. Is it a problem of my PC? I tryed on the server also.

Comment: @LiubovMarkovich 2^35 should be around 262GB which is still a lot but everytime you go up 1 you double the amount of contiguous space of RAM you need. You should look into changing your approach to the problem

Comment: You seem to be using a single element of E in each iteration.

Comment: YES! This was totaly the best idea.

Answer (score 4):

To explain PeterT's comment:

```
const int N=45;
long int toc;
toc = pow(2, N) - 1;
vector<long double > E(toc);
```

Here `toc` is about 2<sup>45</sup>, which is really a huge number, something above 30e12 i.e. 3 times 10<sup>13</sup> (because 2<sup>10</sup> is slightly above a thousand and 2<sup>5</sup> is more than 30, and you could compute that in your head, without any device or paper).

You don't have enough resources to keep that much numbers in your computer (a `long double` takes 8 to 12 bytes each) Even if by some Harry Potter's like miracle you did get such a gigantic computer, since filling a `long double` number could take one or a few nanoseconds, you'll need at least many hours (since 30e12 nanoseconds is 30000 seconds, e.g. more than 8 hours) of CPU time to fill such a gigantic memory (of at least 8*30e12 bytes, e.g. 240 terabytes of RAM; at more than 1000€ for 128Gbytes of consumer-grade DRAM4, that would mean 200k€ for 2000 [DDR4 SDRAM modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM) - no motherboard can handle that much!). Be aware of [limits of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits_of_computation) and [transcomputational problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcomputational_problem).

When coding, keep in mind the actual capacity of your typical computer, and make a guess estimate of the resources (in memory, in disk, in time) needed by your program. The first rules of thumb are: your laptop or desktop computer has less than 128Gbytes of RAM (unless you paid a lot for it; a typical [highend laptop](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/walmart-overpowered-gaming-laptop-17-plus,5555.html) has 16 or 32Gbytes in 2018; with 3000€ to 5000€ I could buy in 2019 a desktop with 128Gigabytes of RAM and 10Terabytes of SSD or disk), it has less than a few terabytes of disk; it makes about 3 to 20 "elementary operations" (I leave you to guess what these [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code) instructions could be) every nanosecond. A whole day lasts 86400 seconds (you can round up that to 1e5). See http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight. A year is 31e6 seconds, a century is more than 3 billions (3.1e9) seconds.

For supercomputers, you need to pay a lot for them (or get some research grant to access them). Look into the [TOP500 list](https://www.top500.org/lists/) to get an idea of their capacities. Today, they are highly parallel computers, and [parallel computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) is a difficult matter.

When you code something, you should make an educated guess on the resources required by your program. So understanding [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and other kinds of [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) (notably [space complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE)) is in practice essential for coding (you should avoid [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion)). Some problems are [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem), others are intractable (read about [computation complexity theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory), learn about the [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)). You need to ask yourself if your problem (or your pretended algorithm) fits into such areas.

Comment: Thanks! But you think the code is correct? I can try it on our server, maybee it will work.

Comment: You probably don't have access to a server with 262TB of RAM. In my understanding, no computer on Earth is powerful enough today.

Comment: Lol, I am stupid) As you can see, we wanted to check out some model using brute-force. To check your own methods. Apparently for large systems checking is problematic.